# 'script' bash command getting hung up in bash function

Tags: linux, bash, sh

So, I would like to be able to run the 'script' bash command and have the output flushed to a named pipe. I know that I can do this with 'script -q -F pipe_name'. However, I would like to put this in a bash function, in a .sh file, and have it still function properly.

When I put the script command in a bash function in a .sh file, source the file, then execute the command, it appears that it's 'hung up.' No output is displayed in the terminal window.

The .sh file:

```
monitor() {
    script -q -F pipe
}
```

Then I try:

```
source monitor.sh
monitor
```

and it gets hung up, not displaying any output.

I expect this to run in a .sh file as it does outside of it. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: If I run the command `script -q -F pipe` in a bash terminal, it says that `-F` is an invalid option. Maybe you meant `-f`? Or is it my bash not being updated?

Comment: @E.Sawyers: My man page for _script_ also doesn't list `-F`. What is this option supposed to do? @Miki4444 : This is not related to the bash version, because _script_ is an external program. It may depend on the _script_ version. Mine is 2.33.1.

Comment: @E.Sawyers: It works for me both in Mac(bash version - 3.2.57) and Linux(bash version - 3.2.57). For Linux, I had to use -f instead of -F .

Comment: @user1934428 You are right, it should depend on the script version. Nevertheless, my bash version is 4.2.46 and my util-linux (where script function is from) version is 2.23.2. For me, it works with -f but no -F, it creates a pipe file with the commands.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS, and script does have the -F option. I ended up getting the command to work by restarting my computer. Extremely weird. However, when I'm reading from the pipe in a python program, I don't see the output until I end the script command. The -F option is supposed to flush the output in realtime. Any ideas?

Comment: Is anything *reading* from the pipe? Any process writing to a pipe blocks until something opens the other end for reading.